# how to change or check the order of the tests using pytest-asyncio

Tags: pytest, pytest-asyncio

I'm using `pytest-asyncio` and can't find any documentation on how to ensure the order of the files running? For example if I have `test_user.py` and `test_item.py` and want `test_user` to run first, is there a way to do that?

Comment: The test modules are usually run in alphabetical order, I'm not aware that using `pytest-asyncio` could change that. If the order is important (which it usually shouldn't be), rename the modules or use something like `pytest-order` to order them.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. I agree on the order part, just some of my initialization is pretty slow, so I'd prefer to do it once. thanks again.